# Center a list of elements in a page

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center a list of elements in a page without redimensioning the elements and at the same time, fit as much as possible in the same row.
I manage to do it with several @media rules for each screen size from 1 element per row up to 4 elements, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in a way that it would fit whatever the width of the page is.
Here is what I've tried and works:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 294px) { .container {
  width: 290px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 584px) { .container {
    width: 580px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 874px) { .container {
    width: 870px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1164px) { .container {
    width: 1160px;
}}

.rectangle {
  width: 286px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: #aeaeae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I viewed your code snippet and I agree it works. Are you trying to avoid writing media queries to get the same result? You'd need js for that.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as in the snippet but without media queries so it works whatever the width is. Do I really need js for that ? I mean it's not a problem but I thought there was a way I didn't know to do it entirely with css

Comment: Js isn't mandatory for it, ok, do you want 4 blocks in a row & the rest of the block will go next row?

Comment: i think the question is well written for a new user, even included a snippet, and pretty clear. good job.

Comment: @Shihab-UlH. I'm trying to make it so whatever the size of the screen is, the element will fill as much width as possible while keeping the list centered, and the elements of the list aligned from left to right. What I did is working exactly like I'd want but it is up to 4 blocks and not up to how much blocks as possible

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to center all the items that fit on one line - then you can use `justify-content` to replace the media queries

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjMNgO?editors=1100)

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 286px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: #aeaeae;
}
```

Comment: justify-content is almost doing the job that I wanted. The only problem is that bottom elements are centered as well and therefore they are not aligned well with the others when there are fewer elements on the last row

Comment: then you should just add a `flex-basis` value that suits your needs then @sleiphir

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I could use flex-basis to align the elements to the left on the list while keeping the list centered on the page

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do when trying to accomplish this is setting `text-align: center;` on the container, (.container in your case). Then for the elements you're wanting to have be centered, setting the display property to `display: inline-block;` (.rectangle in your case). This will put as many elements that'll fit, on to one line. And anything that doesn't fit on to the next, still centered. When you resize your window, the elements move down to the next line as needed.

Change your css to this:

```
    .rectangle {
  width: 286px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: #aeaeae;
  display: inline-block
}
   .container {
  /*display: flex;
  width: max-content;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You'll need to comment out the first two lines in .container for this to work properly. Hopefully this works for you!

EDIT: I thought originally you were wanting your elements to be centered. Now I'm not sure. If you're wanting elements that are on subsequent lines to be left aligned like in your snippet, change `text-align: center;` to `text-align: left;`.

```css
.rectangle {
            width: 286px;
            height: 180px;
            margin-right: 2px;
            margin-left: 2px;
            margin-bottom: 24px;
            background: #aeaeae;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .container {
            /*display: flex;
            width: max-content;*/
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You were right, I try to center the list, but align the element of the list to the left. The problem is that if I put text-align: left then the list is not centered anymore

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 294px) { .container {
  width: 290px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 584px) { .container {
    width: 580px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 874px) { .container {
    width: 870px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1164px) { .container {
    width: 1160px;
}}

.rectangle {
  width: 286px;
  height: 180px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  background: #aeaeae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it in various ways without targeting media queries. Here is one example:
lets wrap the `.rectangle` in another `div`

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Declare 25% width for each rectangle holding `div`:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container > div{
 width: 25%; float: left; padding-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 24px; height: 180px;  
}
.container > div::nth-child(4){
  padding-right: 0;
}
.rectangle{background: green; height: 180px; }
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/yjwWXg)